# How to make association 1 to many by fluent api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, orm, linq2db

I have this model

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="TopicId")]  // Need to remove and go to fluent syntax definition
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TopicId { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey="TopicId", OtherKey="Id")]
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And this query

```
db.Topics.Where(x => x.Id == 6).Select(x =>
       new
       {
          Topic = x,
          MessagesIds = x.Messages.Select(t => t.Id).ToList()
       }).FirstOrDefault();
```

All works fine, but I am searching the way how to make 1 to many assotiation by fluent api.

If I remove attribute

```
[Association(ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="TopicId")]  // This removed
public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
```

And do such way

```
mp.Entity<Topic>().Association(x => x.Messages, (x, y) => x.Id == y.TopicId);
```

Query fails with this

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: body
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Expression body, string
>   name, bool tailCall, IEnumerable parameters)
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Expression body,
>   ParameterExpression[] parameters)
>   LinqToDB.Linq.Builder.ExpressionBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass94_0.b__1(Expression
>   e) LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr,
>   Func func)
>   LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(ICollection source,
>   Func func)
>   LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.TransformX(MethodCallExpression e,
>   Func func)
>   LinqToDB.Expressions.Extensions.Transform(Expression expr,
>   Func func)

Maybe I write assotiation wrong? How is propper way to write 1 to many assotiation in fluent syntax?

Comment: its pretty clear isn't it? primary keys shouldn't be null. are you trying to alter the table with old data within it?

Comment: @Valkyrie they are all have attribute `NotNull` and realy notnull in my tests, or I misunderstand you.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with your configuration (we configure associations in linq2db tests using same approach), so I would suggest to fill in issue. I would suspect some details missing from your sample (e.g. try to remove virtual from property)

Comment: @DLuk Okey, I'll try to make today.